# Customising Google search

Tags: google-search

When I search for something with Google, I often get a comment that goes something like

> Whoa, your search query is too interesting; showing results that other users searched for instead.

(slightly paraphrased), with a link I can click on to show the results for my original query.
So my question is, is there a trick in Google's preferences, or using a command line parameter or something, that I can use to show my own search results immediately, skipping the stupid comment?

Note I don't mind Google asking me "Did you mean to search for (something else)" if it thinks I made a typo. This is about showing me results it knows I didn't ask for!

Comment: Are you sure that's Google you're using? Not any phished search engine that looks like Google? Cause I never came across this.

Comment: As an example, search for something with an underscore. For instance, `one_two`. Google will tell you it shows the results for `one two` (without the underscore) and gives you a link that will actually search for `one_two`, which is what I wanted in the first place.

Comment: wrap the text in double quote. search for "one_two" ..

Comment: Ah, but did you get the same message? The one you never came across?

Comment: By the way, if you turn that into an answer, I can mark is as the correct answer.

Comment: I never came across this -> "Whoa, your search query is too interesting; showing results that other users searched for instead."
What I get is -> http://i.imgur.com/tiN3i.png

Comment: Added it as answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Since you're looking to specify your search terms, you may already know this but you can also exclude certain parameters from your search results; simply add - to your search results.  So you can search for something like "one_two" then add -"three four" -foobar to the end of it and it'll search for one_two but remove results that have the terms "three four" and "foobar" in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your query in double quote, that'll show you the results of the exact term you're searching for.
So if you're trying to search `one_two`, you search for `"one_two"`. that's all.

**Update:**
Check [this page](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861) out for more searching tips of Google.